# jquery validation plugin , how to convert error messages to different lanuages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

hi i am using jquery validation plugin .

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

i set error messages like this

```
        messages: {
            business_name: {
                required: "Enter your Business Name",
                minlength: "At least 3 characters long",
                maxlength:"Maximum length allowed is 250 charactors"
            },
            city: {
                required: "Enter City",
                minlength: "min length 3",
                maxlength:"Max length 250"
            },
            state: {
                minlength: "min length 3",
                maxlength:"Max length 250"
            },
            zip_code: {
                minlength: "min length 3",
                maxlength:"Max length 250"
            },
            address: {
                required: "Enter Address",
                minlength: "min length 3",
                maxlength:"Max length 250"
            },
```

this may be a crazy question . 
i want to display this messages in different languages , instead of type the message in different languages , is there a way to pass my English language messages to some where and convert them in to a language what i want . is this possible in jquery validation plugin .please help . i want to develop my web site in different languages .

Comment: If you want automated translation from English you might want to start with more meaningful sentences so that the translator has something reasonable to work with. E.g., to a translator do you think "Enter city" means "go into the city" or "type the city's name"? Even if you didn't intend to translate to other languages, in plain English you should say "minimum" and "maximum" rather than "min" and "max". (And speaking of "min": there are quite a few cities (or towns) and states in the world with 2-letter names.)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Translation PHP wrapper](http://www.codediesel.com/php/google-translation-php-wrapper/)

This might help you.

If you're able to set it as a variable instead of a string, just pass the variable according to the language you're wanting.

```
$language = $_SESSION['lang'];
```

pass that over to the Google api for the language selection

```
$error_username_raw = "Please enter a username"
```

pass the string into the google api to use translate() and set it to a variable as well

```
$error_username = $error_username_translated;

business_name: {
required : $error_username,
....
}
```

I'm really not sure if you understand or not or even if it will work like that with validator

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  Just change the script to english or any other language you want.

```
   -- jquery.validate.english.js -- 
   var messages = {
       business_name : {
         required: "blah blah"
       }

    }

   -- jquery.validate.otherlanguage.js -- 
   var messages = {
       business_name : {
         required: "blub blub"
       }

    }

    <script src="jquery.validate.english.js"> </script>

    var opt = {
     messages : messages
    }
```